# What is the difference between data and information when it comes to Data Security?

Tags: terminology

I'm currently enrolled for Data Security program and for our assignment the question is to differentiate data and information. What is the difference between those two?

Comment: Hint: Your birthday belongs into one of these categories.

Answer (score 1):

Although not the place to ask this, the difference is easy: 
Data are simply bits of information, but not information itself. When data are processed, interpreted, organized, structured or presented so as to make them meaningful or useful, that is called information. Information provides context for data.

ETTX - data with no meaning (bytes)

TEXT - the same data, but interpreted in a specific order, therefore information.

From a security perspective, you may get some data (like encrypted data) but that does not mean you can access the information contained (encrypted) in it.